# how to do sampling modeling in big data set

Tags: machine-learning

I need to do predictive modeling on top of a 10GB training data set, which cannot fit into the memory (8GB). I am thinking of doing multiple sampling of the big data set, and on each sub-set I do splitting to generate training and validation set to create the model. Is there any better ways to solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Load the data in chunks, then optimize using stochastic gradient descent on random batches of the data until the chunk is exhausted. Bring in the next chunk and continue the gradient descent. This is a nearly perfect use-case for SGD.

If your dataset has an order to it, you may want to consider randomizing the order of the chunks to aid in the gradient descent. Practically, this may not make a difference (but it can, of course). If you're interested in why it might matter, think through the gradient descent math.